# FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Передаю объект своего класса (реализую Parcelable) из одного активити в другое через Intent. Из второго активити в фрагмент расположенный на этой активити (через Bundle).
В логах:

```
E/JavaBinder: !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 2557032)
```

Объек не большой, 4 переменные типа String. 
Какая может быть альтернатива передачи данных между активити ?

UPDATE: В первой активити приходится хранить порядка 1000 объектов своего класса. При повороте экрана все объекты сохраняю след. образом:

```
 @Override
 protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
     super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
     outState.putParcelableArrayList(KEY_RESULT_LIST, (ArrayList<? extends  Parcelable>) resultList);
}
```

Сам подход ниок. Насколько будет оправдан singleton, в данном случае ?

Answer (score 1):

Если только String переменные, да и вообще если переменные у объекта примитивные, то можно наследовать интерфейс Serializable.

```
public class MyClass inplements Serializable {
}
```

В интент закидывается так:

```
MyClass objectToSend = new MyClass();
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putSerializable ("data", objectToSend);
```

В активити получаем так:

```
MyClass obj = (MyClass) getIntent.getSerializableExtra("data");
```

Так же в `Serializable` можно закинуть `ArrayList`

Comment: Serializable, на сколько знаю, медленней, чем Parcelable. Хотя при передачи одного объекта эта разница, наверное, будет не заметна.